# Symmetry matrices, find eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm given by symmetry matrix $A$ and $3$ eigenvalues of it: $1,2,3$. And I know two of it's eigenvectors: $(3,2,1)$ and $(2,-1,-4)$, which corresponds to first two eigenvalues: $A (3,2,1) = (3,2,1)$ and $ A(2,-1,-4) = 2(2,-1,-4)$. The task was about finding the last one eigenvector.

I tried to use the property of symmetry matrices, which imply that all eigenvectors are orthogonal. But all I have is an incomplete linear system:

$$ 
3x + 2y + z = 0  
\\
2x - y - 4z = 0
$$

And I am looking for a hint, how can I find the last part of this system for answering the task question?

Comment: Well, the eigenvectors for an eigenvalue make up a subspace, don't they? In this case, it is a $1$-dimensional subspace and no wonder you have multiple solutions. Any vector you get as a solution (except $(0,0,0)$) will be an eigenvector.

Comment: You can set the scale of the eigenvector by taking any variable and setting it to the constant of your choice, for example, set $x=1$.

Comment: yes, I did it, thank you guys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the cross-product: $(3,2,1)\times(2,-1,-4)=\begin{vmatrix}i&j&k\\3&2&1\\2&-1&-4\end{vmatrix}=-7i+14j-7k$.  This *must* be an eigenvector, since it is the only orthogonal direction left.

Comment: yes, it should work too, thank you)

Answer (score 1):

In general you can find a last eigenvalue of a diagonalisable matrix$~A$ by subtracting the known eigenvalues from the trace of the matrix (which equals the sum of the eigenvalues taken with their multiplicities). Once you know the eigenvalue$~\lambda$, finding the corresponding eigenspace is as usual a question of solving the system for $\ker(A-\lambda I)$. Note that this does not require $A$ to be symmetric, but it needs to be assumed that $A$ is diagonalisable, for otherwise it might be that the final eigenvalue is one that was already known (and which has multiplicity at least $2$ as root of the characteristic polynomial), and the eigenspace found might in this case not give an independent eigenvector.